# UTF-8 mail subject in Magento

Tags: email, utf-8, magento-1.9, subject

I'm terribly sorry for asking this again as I know it's been dealt with like a zillion times. Yes, I've read some 20+ posts in this subject and no I still can't get it to work.

Is there somebody who can boil it down to short simple steps for a n00b like me to just read and do with no brain activity involved? =)

And the million dollar question is:
How do I **not** get "=?utf-8?B?Tnl0dCBrb250bywgICE=?=" in the subject of an email but rather what is readable by humans?

I'm using a fairly new and clean install of Magento 1.9.1 so it shouldn't exist any interference from any extensions.

Comment: From what I gather, Magento uses the Zend Framework for sending emails and initializes Zend_Email() with UTF-8 encoding, then uses BASE64 encoding for headers (see source code under `app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Email`). This seems to be hardcoded in Magento and will result in exactly the kind of headers you see. As changing core Magento code is a bad idea (think about upgrades), you should probably write your own extension for this purpose or use one available. /disclaimer: I'm definitely no Magento expert/.

Comment: I should add that UTF-8 is the safest choice (among with other Unicode encodings) if you ever need to send emails that contain accented characters or non-Latin characters. There is little reason to stick to BASE64 encoding, though: `quoted-printable` can be just as good for general purposes and it is more or less human-readable.

Comment: But if UTF-8 is default, which _is_ what I want, it should be OK but why do I get the garbage in the mail subject?
So is this problem more related to Zend than Magento?

Comment: That's not garbage, but a BASE64-encoded UTF-8 string. Your other encoding choice may be `quoted-printable`, which is _usually_ more human readable (as long as the characters are in the unencoded range). Also, Zend is capable of using either encodings, it is Magento that forces using BASE64 all the time.

Comment: To give you an example, the above subject decoded from BASE64 is "Nytt konto,  !". This string encoded using `quoted-printable` is the same as the original string, because it contains no characters that needs to be "escaped" by the quoted-printable encoding.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are concerned about the MIME representation and encoding? I mean, contemporary email clients are generally capable of properly decoding both UTF-8 and BASE64, so the users should see "Nytt konto,  !", regardless the way it is represented in the email (as long as it is standards-compliant).

Comment: The concern is beacuse "Nytt konto, !" is _not_ what is received as subject. Not in Horde, Squirrelmail, Rainloop nor Thunderbird. So I'm guessing it's not a client issue.

Comment: Oh, ok. At least Thunderbird of these should be able to decode UTF-8/BASE64, so something is probably wrong with the email. Any chance you can share a complete sample (Pastebin, Dropbox, etc.)? I can take a look at the email MIME to see what goes wrong.

Comment: Sure. SO doesn't do PMs I guess. How can I share this with you? And only you.

Comment: I guess you can just redact IP addresses and other sensitive information from the email source. I'm not sure if it's in the spirit of SO, but I have added my email address to my SO profile temporarily if all else fails.

Comment: Using your email. You can delete it now, if you wish. Thanks!